# ¿Que evento usar para cuando la aplicación se cierre desde el administrador de tareas?

Tags: android, xamarin

Tengo una aplicación muy sencilla, únicamente cuenta con `onCreate` y `onDestroy`, necesito avisar por SMS de cuando la aplicación es cerrada en un terminal. El problema es que cuando, desde el *"administrador de tareas"* de android cierro la App, no pasa por el evento `onDestroy`.

¿Como puedo asegurarme de que pase sí o sí por el evento?

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        EnviarSms();
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Pues yo lo que haría sería investigar como saber cuando se abre el administrador de tareas y si se abre enviar el sms y cerrar la app o algo por el estilo. También puede revisar la documentación de android al respecto: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=es-419

Answer (score 3):

En realidad no existe un evento del [ciclo de vida de la activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) que se pudiera llamar cuando se destruye el proceso.

Lo que se realiza regularmente es crear un servicio y el método [onTaskRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) sería llamado al cerrar el proceso.

Crea un servicio:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finaliza aplicación...");
        stopSelf();
    }

}
```

Definelo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
   ...
   ...
    <service
        android:name="com.tototita.MyService"
        android:stopWithTask="true" />

</application>
```

al iniciar tu aplicación puedes iniciar el servicio:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
```

ahora para avisar cuando la aplicación es cerrada el método [onTaskRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) sería llamado.

---

En Xamarin también existe el método [OnTaskRemoved](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Service.OnTaskRemoved/p/Android.Content.Intent/)

> [OnTaskRemoved](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Service.OnTaskRemoved/p/Android.Content.Intent/) Es llamado si el servicio se está ejecutando
>   actualmente y el usuario ha eliminado una tarea que proviene de la
>   aplicación del servicio.

```
namespace MyApp
{
[Service]
public class MyService: Service
{
    static readonly string TAG = "MyService";

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
       Log.Debug(TAG, "onStartCommand()");

    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "onBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
       Log.Debug(TAG, "Finaliza aplicación...");
    }



}
```

Comment: tal vez debería de haber especificado que desarrollo en xamarin, ¿Conoces el equivalente?

Comment: @Aritzbn también tiene  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Service.OnTaskRemoved/p/Android.Content.Intent/